# Select Distinct Records with overlapping conditions

Tags: vertica

I have a query to select count of dates between '2017-01-01' and '2017-03-01' 
is there anyway to calculate separately for '2017-01-01','2017-02-01' and '2017-03-01' without using case statements.

Something like using group by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need function [`date_trunc`](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.2.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/Date-Time/DATE_TRUNC.htm). It will truncate your dates/timestamps to month.

```
daniel=> select date_trunc('month', '2017-01-31'::date);
     date_trunc  
---------------------
 2017-01-01 00:00:00
(1 row)

daniel=> select date_trunc('month', '2017-03-17'::date);
     date_trunc  
---------------------
 2017-03-01 00:00:00
(1 row)
```

i.e. query will look something like:

```
SELECT
    date_trunc('month', date) as 'month',
    count(*)                  as 'count'
FROM
    table
WHERE
    date_trunc('month', date) >= '2017-01-01'
        AND
    date_trunc('month', date) <= '2017-03-01'
GROUP BY
    date_trunc('month', date);
```

---

If you need to generate time series, use in [`row_number() over ()`](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.2.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/Analytic/ROW_NUMBERAnalytic.htm) and any table with enough rows, for example `system_tables`:

```
daniel=> select '2017-01-01'::DATE + cast(row_number() over () - 1 as interval month) from system_tables limit 5;
      ?column?
---------------------
 2017-01-01 00:00:00
 2017-02-01 00:00:00
 2017-03-01 00:00:00
 2017-04-01 00:00:00
 2017-05-01 00:00:00
(5 rows)
```

Also you can try `TIMESERIES` with gap filling:

```
SELECT ts AS 'date' FROM (
    SELECT '2017-01-01'::TIMESTAMP AS tm
        UNION
    SELECT '2017-01-03'::TIMESTAMP AS tm) AS t
TIMESERIES ts AS '8 hours' OVER (ORDER BY tm);

daniel=> \e
        date
---------------------
 2017-01-01 00:00:00
 2017-01-01 08:00:00
 2017-01-01 16:00:00
 2017-01-02 00:00:00
 2017-01-02 08:00:00
 2017-01-02 16:00:00
 2017-01-03 00:00:00
(7 rows)
```

Now, lets combine all together and will count days per month with `date_trunc`:

```
SELECT
    date_trunc('month', T.date) AS 'MONTH',
    count(*)                    AS 'COUNT'
FROM (
    SELECT ts::DATE AS 'date' FROM (
        SELECT '2017-01-01'::TIMESTAMP AS tm
            UNION ALL
        SELECT '2017-03-01'::TIMESTAMP AS tm
    ) AS S
    TIMESERIES ts AS '8 hours' OVER (ORDER BY tm)
) AS T
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;

daniel=> \e
        MONTH        | COUNT
---------------------+-------
 2017-01-01 00:00:00 |    93
 2017-02-01 00:00:00 |    84
 2017-03-01 00:00:00 |     1
(3 rows)
```

Comment: I wanted to include January count in Feb and March as well cumulative count without looping it

Comment: @Swathi8038 take a look on [GROUP BY Clause](https://my.vertica.com/docs/8.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/SELECT/GROUPBYClause.htm%3FTocPath%3DSQL%2520Reference%2520Manual%7CSQL%2520Statements%7CSELECT%7CGROUP%2520BY%2520Clause%7C_____0) - `GROUPING SETS`, `CUBE`, or `ROLLUP` or use in `UNION`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT date, count(*) FROM table WHERE date>='2017-01-01' AND date<='2017-03-01' GROUP BY date;
```

Or you can change dates inclusive or exclusive

Comment: I want as only month start dates, i will be having records of other dates as well

Comment: Then Make sure it will be start date of month in WHERE clause
like `WHERE EXTRACT(DAY FROM date)=1` in MySQL